# Generic filename validation in Azure Data factory for processing files

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm currently looking for a way to validate the files that have been delivered from a client to a storage container. they all have different names and have a Date.
for example :

- AAA_LocalRate_20220905_LC.xlsx
- AAA_PostTaxReport_Q1_LC.xlsx
- AAA_GroupRate_Q2_LC.xlsx
- ABC_Vendors_2022.csv

Now as we need to have some naming convention checks, we have a sql table where we declare the name for each specific source like so:

- AAA_LocalRate_*_LC
- AAA_PostTaxReport_*_LC
- AAA_GroupRate_*_LC
- ABC_Vendors_*

Now what I would like to achieve is to get the metadata from that storage account that will return a list of all files delivered and compare those with a list from a lookup task that gets the files from a sql table with the declared naming conventions.
If there is a match we can process the files in a pipeline, one for the csv's and one for the excel's.

So far I haven't found a way to do that I used Filter, if conditions task, variable comparison, ... I'm really stuck here.

thanks in advance !

Comment: How you are getting files from sql table in adf?

Comment: @Wouter Lefebvre, Are the Number of `_` in your file names are constant? like Is there any pattern in your file names like the date or names which is there as `*` in SQL table will come only after `n` number of `_`s?

Comment: @JayashankarGS I'm only getting string values from my sql table

Comment: @RakeshGovindula No they are not. It depends on the source and name of the file we get delivered. But it will always be 'source_filename_Date/period' or 'source_filename_date/period_LC/USD'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have two files lists(one from Get meta data and another from lookup), you need to use **For Each + Filter** to achieve your requirement.

Give the Lookup output array which consists the pattern to ForEach activity and enable the Sequential in ForEach.

This is my pipeline structure to achieve your requirement:

But this approach only works when each file matches only with one pattern. If any file matches with more than one pattern, then this approach will give duplicates.

[image]

Create string variables `curr_pattern_first`, `curr_pattern_second`, `temp`, `all_matched_files_str` and an array variable `files_arr` in the pipeline variables.

Inside ForEach, Filter the files for every pattern. Your pattern consists two parts, one before and one after the `*`. So, to check both parts, store the two parts in string variables like below.

**First pattern:**

```
@split(item().pattern,'*')[0]
```

[image]

Store the **Second pattern if exists:**

```
@if(not(equals(length(split(item().pattern,'*')),2)),'',split(item().pattern,'*')[1])
```

Now, give the Get Meta data activity child items array to filter activity items and for condition, give the below expression.

```
@and(contains(item().name,variables('curr_pattern_first')),contains(item().name,variables('curr_pattern_second')))
```

[image]

Filter activity will give the output array, convert it as string and concatenate it with `all_matched_files_str` variable like below and store it in `temp` variable.

```
@concat(variables('all_matched_files_str'),',',replace(replace(string(activity('Filters files matches current pattern').output.value),'[',''),']',''))
```

[image]

Reassign the `temp` variable to `all_matched_files_str` variable.

[image]

Now, outside ForEach activity, convert the Json string to proper JSON array with below expression and store it in the `files_arr` variable.

```
@json(replace(concat('[',variables('all_matched_files_str'),']'),'[,','['))
```

[image]

**Result files array:**

[image]

If you want two files lists of `.csv` and `.xlsx`, use two filter activities on the above array and check for the string `.csv` or `.xlsx`.

**My Pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Binary1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                        "partitionOption": "None"
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Filters files matches current pattern",
                            "type": "Filter",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Store the second pattern",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "items": {
                                    "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "condition": {
                                    "value": "@and(contains(item().name,variables('curr_pattern_first')),contains(item().name,variables('curr_pattern_second')))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Store filter output as string in temp",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Filters files matches current pattern",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "temp",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@concat(variables('all_matched_files_str'),',',replace(replace(string(activity('Filters files matches current pattern').output.value),'[',''),']',''))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "store the current pattern",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "curr_pattern_first",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@split(item().pattern,'*')[0]",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "concatenate to final string",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Store filter output as string in temp",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "all_matched_files_str",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@variables('temp')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Store the second pattern",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "store the current pattern",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "curr_pattern_second",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@if(not(equals(length(split(item().pattern,'*')),2)),'',split(item().pattern,'*')[1])",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Final files array",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "files_arr",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@json(replace(concat('[',variables('all_matched_files_str'),']'),'[,','['))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "all_matched_files_str": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "curr_pattern_first": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "temp": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "files_arr": {
                "type": "Array"
            },
            "curr_pattern_second": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```